# Cursor code, not showing the custom cursor set. CSS

Tags: html, css, mouse-cursor

pretty new to CSS and HTML and was hoping somebody could help me fix this. I wanted to be able to change the icon for the cursor although when I run the code, simply no change. A few visits to chatGPT hasnt done me much either. Here's my code:

```
body2 {
  cursor: url("assets/img/wiiu/Smile_icon_32x32.png"), url("assets/img/wiiu/cursor.svg"), auto;
}
```

And yes, it is 32x32.

I've tried moving it to different classes, changing words, changing everything. Although nothing has worked.

Comment: So if you look at the network panel do you see a 404 when it is referencing the icon?

Comment: Hi Mr. Weeb, welcome to SO! Without a [reprex] there's little people can do to help. There's some error/mistake in your code we can't reproduce...

Answer (score 1):

here is a good reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor?retiredLocale=de

So basically you try to applie to a `body2` HTML element you're CSS code. If its a class try the CSS selector `.body2 {}` or in the case its an id of a HTML element `#body2 {}`.

In you're css you've got one main picture and the second one as fallback. Just make sure you set the correct path corresponding to the location of you're CSS file.
To ensure that, you can also try the full path instead of the relativ one like `C:\Users\xxx\Smile_icon_32x32.png`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong css declaration, your code will only work if you have defined a custom html element having `<body2>` as tag.

What you probably want is:

body { ... }
applied to `<body>` tag

or a css class

.body { ... }
applied to  or any other tag having `body` as class.

or a css id

#body { ... }
applied to  or any other kind of tag with `body` as id.

Alternatively check in the browser console if the rule is applied and if the image path is resolved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where http://example.com/32x32/990000/fff.png&text=PNG don't exist and https://dummyimage.com/32x32/009900/fff.gif&text=GIF exist so the gif will be used instead of the png :

```css
        .body2 {
            display:inline-block;
            cursor: url("http://example.com/32x32/990000/fff.png&text=PNG"),url("https://dummyimage.com/32x32/009900/fff.gif&text=GIF"), auto;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="body2">display</div>
```